# Replacing Words in TextField In Django

Tags: python, django, replace

In django, in TextField, how to we replace,

```
[vimeo 123456]
```

with

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/123456" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to have the HTML in the `TextField`.  First, it would make editing a pain (you'd have to write code to translate back, which will be more difficult than forward); second, it would waste disk on storing a lot of HTML in the database; and finally, it would make it harder to fix bugs later (such as if Vimeo changed their URL format).

You have two options that I can see:

#### 1. View Function

Do this translation in your view function.  Your view function would have a line like:

```
context["commentText"] = process_markup(thePost.commentText)
```

Then, in your template file, you need to mark the field as `safe` since you've already filtered it:

```
{{ commentText|safe }}
```

#### 2. Custom Filter

Do this translation in a custom filter tag, like the `restructuredtext` filter in `django.contrib.markup`.  This is what sebpiq recommended, and is probably the better option.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
import re

@stringfilter
def mymarkup(value):
    return process_markup(value)
```

Then, in your template file, you need to call your filter:

```
{{ commentText|mymarkup }}
```

---

In both cases, you would need to write `process_markup(value)`, which would look something like:

```
import re

_TAGS = [
    # First, escape anything that might be misinterpreted.  Order is important.
    (r'&', r'&amp;'),
    (r'<', r'&lt;'),
    (r'>', r'&gt;'),
    (r'"', r'&quot;'),
    (r"'", r'&#39;'),

    # Simple tags
    (r'\[b\]', r'<b>'),
    (r'\[/b\]', r'</b>'),

    # Complex tags with parameters
    (r'\[vimeo +(\d+) *\]', r'<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/\g<1>"'
        r' width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe>'),
]

def process_markup(value):
    for pattern, repl in _TAGS:
        value = re.sub(pattern, repl, value)
    return value
```

There are probably better ways to write this function, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in your `TextField`. Rather in the templates. But then you have to parse the value, so I would suggest you write a simple template filter :

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
import re

@stringfilter
def textfieldtourl(value):
    #parsing of your '[vimeo <id>]'
    #return "http://player.vimeo.com/video/<id>"
```

And then in template :

```
<iframe src="{{ my_object.my_text_field|textfieldtourl }}" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Where `my_object` is the object on which your `TextField` is defined, `my_text_field` is the name of your TextField, and `textfieldtourl` is the name of the filter you'll define to replace a code like `[vimeo 1235]` by an actual url.

[More infos on writing custom template fiters](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: Think a blog system and when i add a content, maybe i will want to use [vimeo 123456] combination. So, we should solve this out of templates i think. Because maybe i won't use this. What do you think?

Comment: "and when i add a content, maybe i will want to use [vimeo 123456] combination" do you mean that the user that actually add the content would write "[vimeo 123456]" in some form field ??? If it's not what you meant I think I didn't get it ...

Comment: Sorry for my low level English. In my blog system i will use this code, maybe in first line, or end of the content, or somewhere in the content. So this sould happen in textfield. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your level of English is fine, it is just that your explanation is not very clear ! "this code" what code (do you mean "<iframe> ...") ? "content" which content (do you mean your html page) ? Anyways, you should not store html in your models, so whatever you want to do, I advise you to store "[vimeo 123456]" in your TextField, and to format this in your template into a url (like I told you in the answer).

Comment: I am newbie in django also. If you understand me, ok, i will try your suggestion in the evening. I will write your first code in templatetags folder? And second code, in the template file. If i write [vimeo 123456], it will replace with iframe code. Thank you again.